# which one can be taken as the upper bound for $|f'(0)|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

If $f(z)$ is analytic  on $D$ where $D=\{(x,y):|x|\leq a, |y|\leq b, a \ge b\}$. If $f(z)$satisffies the inequality $|f(z)|\leq M$ on the boundary of $D$ then which one can be taken as the upper bound for $|f'(0)|$?

(A)$\frac{2M(a+b)}{\pi a b}$

(B)$\frac{2\pi a b}{M^2}$

(C)$\frac{2M^2}{ 2\pi a b}$

(D)$\frac{2M(a+b)}{ \pi b^2}$

My ideas on this problem.

$|f'(0)|=|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^2}dz|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{\gamma}|\frac{f(z)}{z^2}||dz|\leq \frac{M}{2\pi }\frac{\int_{\gamma}|dz|}{|ab|}$

($\because |z|\ge |b|$ and $|z|\ge |a| \implies |z|^2\ge |ab|$)

Comment: Note that the length of the boundary (i.e. the curve $\gamma$ in your estimate, which is just a rectangle of sides $2a$ and $2b$) is $4(a+b)$. The absolute value around $a$ and $b$ can be dropped since they are both positive.

Comment: Okay. Thank you

Comment: (a) and (d) are correct answers. am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct for all $z$ on the boundary of $D$:

> $\because |z|\ge |b|$ and $|z|\ge |a| \implies |z|^2\ge |ab|$

We can say that $|z|\ge |b|$ **or** $|z|\ge |a|$. Since $a \ge b$ it follows that $|z^2| \ge b^2$ in any case, and this leads to estimate (D).

Comment: Why? |$z|≥|b|⟹|z|\neq 0 \implies |a||z|\ge |b||a|$and also we have| $z|\ge |a|\implies |z|^2\ge |a| |z|.$applying  transitivity $|z||z|\ge |a||b|$. right?

Comment: @Unknownx: No, $|z| \ge |a|$ does not hold everywhere on the boundary of $D$. Take for example $a=2$, $b=1$, and $z = i$.

Comment: But in your example $|a|>|z|$

Comment: @Unknownx: I don't get you.  For $a=2$ and $b=1$ the point  $z=i$ lies on the boundary of the rectangle $D=\{(x,y):|x|\leq a, |y|\leq b\}$, but your estimate  $|z|^2 \ge ab$ does *not hold.*

Comment: okay. Thank you. Now I understood my mistake.